# Finding Min and Max of Circle Radius

Tags: java

Alright so all of the methods word except the minMax method, this is a file that takes information from my CircleWithPrivateDataFields.java 
If you need any of the code from that you can let me know and I can reedit this file with the appropriate files.

This is my error: double cannot be converted to CircleWithPrivateDataFields

what will I have to do for this to work, I know I'm very close, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Remember it's the minMax method that only needs work.

Thanks in advance!

```
 public class TotalArea {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Declare circle array
  CircleWithPrivateDataFields[] circleArray;

  //Create circleArray
  circleArray = createCircleArray();

  printCircleArray(circleArray);

  minMax(circleArray);        
 }

public static CircleWithPrivateDataFields[] createCircleArray() {
  CircleWithPrivateDataFields[] circleArray = new CircleWithPrivateDataFields[5];

  for (int i=0; i < circleArray.length; i++) {
     circleArray[i] = new CircleWithPrivateDataFields(Math.random() * 100);
  }
     //Return circle array
  return circleArray;
}//end createCircleArray method

/*

  takes the array of circles and determines the 
  smallest and largest circles in the array and prints out their information.

*/

public static void minMax(CircleWithPrivateDataFields[] circleArray) {
System.out.println();
double max;

  for (int i=0; i<circleArray.length; i++) {
     if(circleArray[i].getRadius() > 0) {
        circleArray[i] = max;
     }

  }
}



   //Add circle areas
     public static double sum(CircleWithPrivateDataFields[] circleArray) {
        //Initalize sum
  double sum = 0;

        //Add areas to sum
  for (int i=0; i<circleArray.length; i++)
     sum += circleArray[i].getArea();

  return sum;
 }
}
```

Comment: While there are some things logically not very understandable in the program, the compiler error is due to this line
    `circleArray[i] = max;`
You have to declare `max` as `CircleWithPrivateDataFields` if you wish to assign it to the array.

Comment: How is it going @Justin?

Comment: Well! Figured it out, took a little different route... set the double min and max equal to `circleArray[0].getRadius()` then set two for loops to loop through the array to find the min and max with a couple if/else statements. Thanks! @StéphaneBruckert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `max` (a `double`) to `circleArray` which is an array of `CircleWithPrivateDataFields`.

You have to make sure that `circleArray` is an array of `double` or that the `CircleWithPrivateDataFields` class extends `Double`.